# Control vibration for our application irrespective of mobile state

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, vibration

Can we control vibration mode of mobile phone for our application.I mean we cab turn on/Off vibration that should change for our app itself.

Can we do that in latest ios version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Note that you need to add the AudioToolbox framework and import the following header file:

```
import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Hope it helps.